# Are non-covariant Schwinger terms related to the renormalization of composite operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, operators, renormalization, commutator

In Section 5.5 of Duncan's *The Conceptual Framework of Quantum Field Theory*, he shows that theories that are not ultra-local has Schwinger terms:
$$
[\mathcal H_\text{int}(\mathbf x_1,t),\mathcal H_\text{int}(\mathbf x_2,t)]=\text{derivatives of }\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf x_1-\mathbf x_2).
$$
The time-ordered product $\mathcal H_\text{int}$ of these theories are not Lorentz invariant. In fact, under a Lorentz transformation,
$$
\text{change of }\mathcal T\{\mathcal H_\text{int}(x_1)\mathcal H_\text{int}(x_2)\}=\text{spatial derivatives of }\delta^{(4)}(x_1-x_2).
$$
For example, as shown in Section 6.2 of Weinberg's QFT vol.1, the propagator of a massive vector field contains a non-covariant term. A theory with interaction $\mathscr H(x)=v_\mu(x)J^\mu(x)$ with classical background $J^\mu(x)$ will then satisfy
$$
\mathcal T\{\mathscr H(x_1)\mathscr H(x_2)\}=\ :\mathscr H(x_1)\mathscr H(x_2):\ +\ \underbrace{\text{something Lorentz-invariant}\ +\ \text{const.}\times(J^0(x_1))^2\delta^{(4)}(x_1-x_2)}_{J^\mu(x_1)J^\nu(x_2)\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x_1-x_2)}.
$$
Here, $\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x_1-x_2)$ is the propagator. Notice that Weinberg's $\mathscr H(x)$ and Duncan's $\mathcal H_\text{int}(x)$ are actually the same thing. They are normal-ordered products of elementary fields.

**My question:** Is this somehow related to the ambiguity when defining a composite operator, which needs renormalization and stuff? In particular, can we define a renormalized composite operator "$\mathcal R\{\mathscr H^2(x)\}$" that is Lorentz-invariant?

A naive guess goes something like this. Instead of using point-splitting regularization (as is done when defining normal-ordered products), we use Pauli-Villars, for example. Then, the delta-function will be regularized to be
$$
\delta^{(4)}_{(\Lambda)}(0)=\int_0^\Lambda\frac{{\rm d}^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{ik0}\sim\Lambda^4.
$$
And the propagator now has a well-defined regularized value $\Delta_{\mu\nu}^{(\Lambda)}(0)$. Perhaps we can define
$$
\mathcal R_\Lambda\{\mathscr H^2(x)\}:=J^\mu(x)J^\nu(x)\Delta_{\mu\nu}^{(\Lambda)}(0)-\text{const.}\times(J^0(x))^2\delta^{(4)}_{(\Lambda)}(0).
$$
It seems plausible that the above expression defines a Lorentz-invariant composite operator, in the sense that
$$
\lim_{\Lambda\to\infty}\langle0|\mathcal T\{\,\mathcal R_\Lambda\{\mathscr H^2(x)\}\cdots\,\}|0\rangle\quad<\quad\infty,\quad\text{for all possible insertions away from }x.
$$

**My question (continued):** Does the above definition makes sense? If it does, how is it related to the Lagrangian formalism? In particular, we know that the Lagrangian formalism automatically generates the non-covariant terms to add to $\mathscr H(x)$ in order to cancel the Schwinger terms and restore Lorentz invariance. Is there some way to interpret this procedure as defining Lorentz-invariant composite operators?

---

I'm sorry if the question seems a bit vague and somewhat whimsical. This is partly due to the fact that Schwinger terms are nowhere to be seen in the Lagrangian formalism, and renormalization of composite operators are discussed in textbooks almost exclusively using path integrals and Lagrangians. Things are complicated further that, to discuss these fundamental issues, it's important that we stand on solid logical grounds, but as you can see, I have referred to Weinberg and Duncan who are not unwilling to sacrifice rigor for physical insight.

Because of this, there is a slight chance that my question is utterly nonsensical or plainly wrong due to some confusion of concepts. After all, I am trying to tackle problems intrinsic to the operator formalism using tools developed for the Lagrangian formalism. For this, I apologize.

Comments as to how to sharpen the question are most welcome!

Comment: Is this not related to the extra terms that come from a functional integral analysis of symmetries? See Peskin & Schroeder Sec. 9.6

Comment: @flippiefanus I don't see how these two notions are related. As far as I know, the contact terms in the Schwinger-Dyson equation correspond to the time derivative of time-ordering in the operator formalism. In particular, they are there for all theories. However, the non-covariant Schwinger terms come from the time-ordering itself, with no derivatives; and they don't appear for all fields (for example, scalar fields don't have Schwinger terms).